# Remove portion of a string after a particular character from the end of the string

Tags: php

I need to remove all characters from a string after a particular character from the end. The below code works when it contains only one #
eg:

```
$variable = "8233 Station #2212";
echo trim(substr($variable, 0, strpos($variable, "#")));
```

result: "8233 Station";
But if the string contains more than one # I need to avoid the strings after the last #

```
 $variable = "8233 Station #2211 #2212";
```

The result i need in the above situation is "8233 Station #2211"

Comment: Hey, i think you can specify the third optional (offset) of strpos to search the position start from the end of the string. Ref : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strrpos` to get position of last matching element

```
//$variable = "8233 Station #2212"; //8233 Station
$variable = "8233 Station #2211 #2212";
echo trim(substr($variable, 0, strrpos($variable, "#"))); //8233 Station #2211
```

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done with `substr()` which extract the string from a string and `strrpos()` which return last occurrence of a character, try like below:

```
<?php
$variable = "8233 Station #2211 #2212";
echo substr($variable, 0, strrpos($variable, "#"));
```

check the output here: https://eval.in/813032

Comment: trim the result will be better.

Answer (score 1):

Use [strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) instead of [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

**strpos** — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string

**strrpos** — Find the position of the last occurrence of a substring in a string

```
$variable = "8233 Station #2212 #2212";
echo trim(substr($variable, 0, strrpos($variable, "#")));
```